# Как загрузить файл из сети при сборке с помощью cmake?

Tags: c++, linux, сеть, cmake, сборка

Можно ли как-то заменить код ниже, чтобы он делал тоже самое, и работал на любой системе?
Конкретно тут проблема в wget, которая свойственна для linux.

```
execute_process(COMMAND wget -O CMakeLists.txt http://example.com/file.txt
        WORKING_DIRECTORY "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/download_dir"
        )
```

Comment: Wget и на винду отлично ставится.

Comment: Используйте curl - на Windows 10 он есть из коробки.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Модуль [FetchContent](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html) - как раз для этого.

Comment: Близко к тому что я хочу, но, при получении файла с помощью этого способа, сборщик пытается распаковать архив. В моём случае нет архива. Мне нужно сохранить txt файл в определённую директорию. Я просмотрел документацию к FetchContent и не нашёл способа для получения файла без распаковки, либо же я глуп и слеп, что вполне вероятно.

Comment: @llollcat В `FetchContent_Populate` нужно указать `DOWNLOAD_NO_EXTRACT`. В документации об этом одна строчка, сложно заметить.

Comment: Хотя, если вам нужно просто скачать один файлик, то `file(DOWNLOAD ...)` может быть лучшей альтернативой.

Comment: да, то что я и хотел изначально сделать.